# NOT EXISTS seems to fail in this case - why?

Tags: sql, exists

I have this query, which returns a number of rows:

```
-- 
-- documents -> document_tags -> tag_groups -> user_groups
--
SELECT documents.id, user_groups.user_id
FROM documents
  JOIN document_tags ON documents.id = document_tags.document_id
  JOIN tag_groups ON document_tags.tag_id = tag_groups.tag_id
  JOIN user_groups ON tag_groups.group_id = user_groups.group_id 
WHERE
  documents.id = 314
```

The fact that a number of rows are returned, tells me that the `document` with ID 314 is associated with one or more `document_tags`, which are in turn related to one or more `tag_groups`, which are in turn associated  with one or more `user_groups`. The query returns these associated users (in the 2nd column of the SELECT output).

Now I want to restructure the query - to show me the *orphaned* documents... **that are NOT associated with ANY users whatsoever** ... so I use `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT documents.id
FROM documents
  JOIN document_tags ON documents.id = document_tags.document_id
  JOIN tag_groups ON document_tags.tag_id = tag_groups.tag_id
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM user_groups 
    WHERE user_groups.group_id = tag_groups.group_id 
  )
```

If you compare the two queries, you'll see that the first two joins are identical - and the third join has moved into the NOT EXISTS.

I would not expect this second query to return document 314 - because the first query returns users that ARE associated with it. **And yet, this second query returns document id 314... as an orphaned document**.

Why?

I am probably missing something obvious - but I can't see what. Help?

Comment: It's possible there are `tag_groups` that are orphaned and `tag_groups` that are not orphaned.  Try `LEFT JOIN user_groups` and see what you get.

Comment: @Bacon Bits: you mean in the 1st query? What would that prove - it already returns rows, showing that document 314 is associated with users...

Comment: Yes the first query with a LEFT JOIN.  Your EXISTS query is joining to  user_groups to tag_groups.  That means the second query isn't showing orphaned documents, it's showing orphaned tag_groups.  Those aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: @BaconBits: Yep, that made it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document 314 is associated (via document_tags) with many tag_groups. Some of those tag_groups have associated user_groups (making the first query succeed), others don't have associated user_groups (making the second query succeed).

That is, your second query doesn't ask "is this document NOT associated with ANY users whatsoever?", it asks "is this document associated with at least one tag_group that doesn't have a corresponding user_group?".

Comment: Thanks! Temporary blindness :-)

Answer (score 0):

That document 314 is returned from the second query means that document 314 has *some* tags that are in *some* tag groups that don't have associated user groups.

Document 314 might still have other tags, or the tags it has might be in still other tag groups, that *have* associated user groups, thus why the first query also returns a non-empty result.